# Capture values between double brackets

Tags: awk, sed, grep

I have a data in a file as `{{1,department}}`.

I need to capture the values as given below:

```
val1=1
val2=department
```

I tried awk command for data with single {}, it worked. but for double {{}} the command is not working.

the command i used is:

```
`var1=`echo $line | awk -F '[{}]' '{print $2}' | awk -F '[,]' '{print $1}'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ echo "{{1,department}}" | awk -F "{{|}}|," '{print $3}'
department

$ echo "{{1,department}}" | awk -F "{{|}}|," '{print $2}'
1
```

Comment: can u explain it pls..

Comment: we have three seperators. 1. {{ 2.}} 3. ,(comma). based upon that, we are printing the values. so {{ is taken as one separator.

Answer (score 4):

With GNU `grep` and any POSIX shell:

```
out=$(grep -Po '\{\{\K.*?(?=\}\})' < your-file)
val1=${out%%,*}
val2=${out#*,}
```

- `-P`: tells `grep` to use perl compatible regular expressions for it's `\K` and `(?=)` operators
- `\K`: sets the start of the *returned* value. `a\Kb` matches on `ab` but returns `b`. So here, we match on `{{...` but only return `...` to exclude `{{` from the output.
- `(?=...)` achieves the same thing for `}}`. It's a look-ahead operator that matches with 0 width if `...` matches there without `...` being included in the returned value
- so `$out` ends up with `1,department`. We use the `${var%%pattern}` and `${var#pattern}` standard shell operators to extract the part before and after the first comma.

That assumes the file contains only one `{{...}}` occurrence and that it contains at least one comma.

POSIXly, you can replace that `grep` command with:

```
sed -n 's/.*{{\([^}]*\)}}.*/\1/p'
```

Now if you have

```
some text {{1,department}} other text
```

in a shell variable, you can also extract it with:

- `zsh`

  ```
  if [[ $string =~ '\{\{([^},]*),([^}]*)\}\}' ]]; then
    val1=$match[1] val2=$match[2]
  fi
  ```
- `bash`

  ```
  if [[ $string =~ \{\{([^},]*),([^}]*)\}\} ]]; then
    val1=${BASH_REMATCH[1]} val2=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
  fi
  ```

Comment: can u explain me this.. also i m having line in a variable.. not in a file. say $line. How will i use command for same

Comment: i have the file with many {{}} with each occurring on different line. So i m reading each line in a loop  as $ line and processing each further. So how to use the same command on a variable

Answer (score 1):

You can print the values (with a leading space) with:

```
$ echo "{{1,department}}" | awk -F '[ {},]' 'NF=NF'
 1 department
```

That will allow to read the values:

```
read val1 val2 <<<$(echo "{{1,department}}" | awk -F '[ {},]' 'NF=NF')
```

This will work for one bracket and any additional fields:

```
$ echo "{{1,department,name,list}}" | awk -F '[ {},]' 'NF=NF'
 1 department name list
```

A similar solution is possible with grep:

```
$ echo '{1,department}' | grep -Po '(?<={|,)[^{,}]*(?=,|})'
1
department

$ echo '{{1,department}}' | grep -Po '(?<={|,)[^{,}]*(?=,|})'
1
department

$ echo '{{1,department,name,list}}' | grep -Po '(?<={|,)[^{,}]*(?=,|})'
1
department
name
list
```

From a variable in the shell it needs to match the exact number of fields:

```
$ value='{{1,department}}'
$ re='\{\{([^},]*),([^}]*)\}\}'
$ [[ $value =~ $re ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[@]:1}"
1 department
```